# How to write a security rule to allow read without using auth variable

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to write Security rules, but I am bit confused on writing it. For my case I am not authenticating the users using Firebase, but I have node in database which has child named by usernames. I am trying to achieve logic like this: for any child of this node if value is true then he can move on  further or else not. Here is my sample node

```
"Customers":{
    "John":"true",
    "Jack":"false"
  }

  "Messages":{
     "Message1":{
  ....
   }, 
  },
```

And here is my rules node where I am confused.I have tried using "$" wild card variable but getting error that variable is unknown.

```
  "rules":{
    "Messages":{
     ".read":"root.child('Customers').child($name).val()===true",
     ".write":"root.child('Customers').child($name).val()===true"
    }
  }
```

I think the "$" variable can't be used this way. So how should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you decide which user to check for value? You must have a value for comparison. If you want a logic like users can see their own messages, you should add an `Username` field under messages node. Like;

```
"Messages":{
     "Message1":{
       "John": {
        },
     ....
   }, 
  }
```

And with this field you can do this;

```
"rules":{
    "Messages":{ 
      "$userId" : {
         ".read":"root.child('Customers').child($userId).val()===true",
         ".write":"root.child('Customers').child($userId).val()===true"
       }
    }
  }
```